# Redireccionar puerto 80 a puerto 8080

Tags: java, tomcat, vps, plesk

Tengo un VPS con SO Centos 8. Mi objetivo es que se ejecuten aplicaciones web Java que corran sobre Tomcat 9 en dicho VPS.

He instalado Java y he instalado Tomcat. He conseguido arrancarlo y ahora consigo acceder al manager del tomcat a través de:

http://midominio.com:8080

Me gustaría que los usuarios no tuvieran que introducir el puerto en la URL, y entiendo que para lograr esto habría que desviar las llamadas al puerto 80 al puerto 8080.

He intentado todo lo que he visto por ahí:

- Cambiar el 8080 al 80 en la etiqueta Connector del fichero server.xml del directorio conf del Tomcat.
- Redireccionar mediante ipTables con un comando del estilo "-A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080".

Observación: en el VPS tengo instalado PLESK y el dominio está asociado a PLESK. Si meto https://midominio.com accedo a la página de prueba del servidor Apache HTTP.

De alguna manera creo que el puerto 80 está "ocupado" por PLESK y por eso está ignorando el resto de configuraciones que he probado, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo solucionarlo.

Si me pudieran ayudar estaría eternamente agradecido.

Saludos.

Comment: Una vez cambiada la configuración haz reiniciado el servidor para que te coja los cambios?

Comment: Pues no lo había hecho, pero acabo de probar y todo sigue igual. Muchas gracias. Creo que el problema es que PLESK hace que el servicio Apache HTTP esté escuchando el puerto 80. ¿Alguna idea de cómo cambiar esto?

Comment: onseguistes solucionarlo?. Estoy en el mismo problema con plesk como interfaz sobre ubuntu

Te agradezco la info si lo solucionastes,

saludos.

Comment: esta pregunta tiene que ver con devops... no es un problema de programacion

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].